# Laravel 5.3: Password reset - Undefined variable: token

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Im using the built in laravel 'auth' view templates and managed to get a email link sent out, but when clicking on the link im redirected to the below url.

The URL seems correct, but once clicked I get the error: Undefined variable: token...which references this line `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">` on the reset.blade.php. I have commented this line out and the route functions fine.

I can see by the url that the token is being set , but I dont know why it is not being set as the `$token` variable...

- I followed the documentation, but it doesnt mention anything else, is there another step im missing?
- How Can I set this url password token to a variable accessible in the view?

**URL**

```
http://project.dev/password/reset/b1d3e738a6a7a0dbee1eec6040e46b4f191ab619b95dd9864dcd9e24765ee1ed
```

Comment: where you are passing the token in reset view

Comment: Ahh i c...im not actually passing the token to the view. I was overriding the 'showResetForm' to a custom view location without including the token. I take it the URL token is taken and set as the `$token` in one of the functions in the `ResetsPasswords.php`?